# why I am getting none in recursion ?(in this program)

Tags: python

```py
def inp():
    try:
        k=input("enter")
        l=int(k)
        return l
    except :
        inp()

print(inp())
```

```
enterll
enter6
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need `return inp()` in the `except` block.

Comment: i tried but i  got this

Comment: def inp():
    try:
        k=input("enter")
        l=int(k)
        return inp()
    except :
        inp()

print(inp())

Comment: enterll
enterkk
enter55
enterll
enter55
enter5
enter

Comment: And what's the issue now?

Comment: its keep on asking me to enter a value

Comment: You didn't edit the right line. Only change the except block to `return inp()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of the recursive call in the `except` block; otherwise, `None` is implicitly returned as you did not explicitly return anything.

```py
def inp():
    try:
        k = input("enter")
        l = int(k)
        return l
    except ValueError:
        return inp()
```

Answer (score 0):

After handling the exception, there is not return value.  This is the problem when you have multiple returns.  You can fix it with one return

```
def inp():
    try:
        k=input("enter")
        l=int(k)
    except :
        l = inp()
    return l
```

or add a return in the exception handler

```
def inp():
    try:
        k=input("enter")
        l=int(k)
        return l
    except :
        return inp()
```